# Microsoft Azure Cognitive Services - Bing Text to Speech API - Play audio using javascript

Tags: text-to-speech, azure-cognitive-services, bing-speech

I am following this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech/api-reference-rest/bingvoiceoutput) to convert text to speech using the Text To Speech REST API.

I'm successfully able to get a valid response using `Postman` and I'm able to pay the audio in `PostMan`. But I am not able to play the audio using `JavaScript`. Below is my `Javascript` code. I'm not sure what to do with the `response`.

```
function bingSpeech(message) {
    var authToken = "TokenToCommunicateWithRestAPI";

    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();

    var params = `<speak version='1.0' xml:lang='en-US'><voice xml:lang='en-US' xml:gender='Female' name='Microsoft Server Speech Text to Speech Voice (en-US, JessaRUS)'>${message}</voice></speak>`;

    http.open('POST', 'https://speech.platform.bing.com/synthesize', true);

    //Send the proper header information along with the request
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/ssml+xml");
    http.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "bearer " + authToken);
    http.setRequestHeader("X-Microsoft-OutputFormat", "audio-16khz-32kbitrate-mono-mp3");

    http.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
            // I am getting the respone, but I'm not sure how to play the audio file. Need help here
        }
    }
    http.send(params);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Trying to figure out the same with Azure TTS service

Comment: Hi @ElleryFamilia, nope. Please let me know if you have found a solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I referred to the following repository for my code in Java. It plays the audio in IDE and saves the audio file to your system.

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/Cognitive-Speech-TTS/tree/master/Samples-Http/Java/TTSSample/src/com/microsoft/cognitiveservices/ttssample

Comment: Please include the solution in your actual answer, as it otherwise becomes useless once the linked resource becomes unavailable.